# Reading Facebook Insights

Tags: facebook-insights

I'm trying to read insights from a facebook page using Insights Table with FQL or with Graph API. I've noticed that the only public fields are page_fans_country and page_storytellers_fan_country. Are all the other fields visible only by the page admin? There isn't a way to read the page_fans metric for example?
Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

If it´s not public, you need to be admin, of course. But if you just need the actual fan count, it´s easier to use the Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/[vanity-url]/

Just put it in the Browser and you will get all public information of the page ("likes").
Of course you can also use the PHP or JS SDK:

```
//JavaScript
FB.api('/[vanity-url]', function(response) {
   ...
});
//PHP
$response = $facebook->api('/[vanity-url');
```

Comment: I need a statistic about the fan_count in the time (for example in the last month), so only the actual fan_count isn't enough for my purpose. For this reason I thought about using insights data. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: yeah, i thought so. that´s not possible without being admin, unfortunately. monitoring tools often do this with a cron job, getting the daily fan count every night.